# Override FOSUserBundle EmailConfirmationListener Error argument "$mailer" of method "__construct()

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

Maybe someone can help me. I use `fos_user_bundle` in my project `Symfony 4`. I override EmailConfirmationListener in `service.yaml`, but have an error:

```
Cannot autowire service "App\EventListener\EmailConfirmationListener": 
argument "$mailer" of method "__construct()" references interface 
"FOS\UserBundle\Mailer\MailerInterface" but no such service exists. You 
should maybe a  
lias this interface to one of these existing services: 
"App\Mailer\Mailer", "send_mail", "fos_user.mailer.default", 
"fos_user.mailer.twig_swift", "fos_user.mailer.noop".
```

See below for my `services.yaml` file:

```
fos_user.listener.email_confirmation:
    class:      App\EventListener\EmailConfirmationListener
    arguments:
    - '@send_mail'
    - '@fos_user.util.token_generator'
    - '@router'
    - '@session'
    tags:
    - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }

send_mail:
    class: App\Mailer\Mailer
    arguments:
        - '@mailer'
        - '@router'
        - '@templating'
        -
            confirmation.template: '%fos_user.registration.confirmation.template%'
            resetting.template: '%fos_user.resetting.email.template%'
            from_email:
                confirmation: '%fos_user.registration.confirmation.from_email%'
                resetting: '%fos_user.resetting.email.from_email%'
```

Please, help me, what I did wrong?

Comment: You need to adjust your services.yaml file to exclude the App\EventListener directory.  Or, and I know this may sound confusing, change your service definition to use the class name as the service id then add an alias for fos_user.listener.email_confirmation.  Using the class name will get rid of the autowire error.  And then the alias will be used by the rest of the bundle.